# C# Get ID from combobox item and save it to settings.settings

Tags: c#, combobox

I set in combobox the `Data source from SQL` in the `Data Binding Mode` where I have ID and Name.

Now I want, when the user choose the `combobox` and choose the `name`, the `ID` of the `name` will be stored in `settings.settings`. So next time user run the app dont need choose it again.

I try it with:

```
private void cbWorkingPlace_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int NameId= Int32.Parse(cbName.SelectedIndex.ToString());

            Properties.Settings.Default.NameId= NameId;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        }
```

My problem is, if I change the `combobox`, then the `ID` is saved OK, but when I close the app the `ID` is changed to `-1`

How can I prevent this??

Comment: check the value before save, because -1 is a special case. and consider save in other events such as `Form.Closing`

Comment: Do you load this value after populating the data?
`cbName.SelectedIndex = Properties.Settings.Default.NameId;` is setting the combobox index to saved value.
Give us more code.

Comment: i add to `Form1_FormClosing` event the same  `Properties.Settings.Default.NameId= NameId           Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` then i add breakpoint, when i check the value is OK, but saved is `-1`

Comment: define a private int value `sel`, in SelectedIndexChanged add if statement to check the value and only when `index != -1` then assign to `sel`, then in `Form1_FormClosing` save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not writing to `Settings` every time the `ComboBox` index is changed.

Bind your `ComboBox`'s value to a custom Property, once a certain event is invoked store the data of the Property in `Settings`. This could be done through a "Save button", which would give the user a clear feedback of what is happening.

An alternative could be to open another view to get to these settings, once there the user needs to close the view to get back, save your settings at that point.

It's always a good idea to validate the data you are saving/using, so binding directly to your data-store isn't such a great idea anyway.

Comment: ok, i disable the  `SelectedIndexChanged event` just the `Form1_FormClosing  event` now, its ok